# Count the same value number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm working on a challenge where I have to find the smallest value in an array and be able to count it if the number occurs more than once. I think I have the format down, but it gives me one more count than there are numbers(4 instead of 3). Can anyone give me some tips? Appreciate any help!

```js
function small(array) {
  var smallest = array[0];
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] < smallest) {
      smallest = array[i];
    }
    if(smallest===array[i]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

small([5,6,2,2,2]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whenever you will get new smallest, then reset is required.

Why its needed to reset count to 0 not 1 ?

because condition is checking with smallest === arr[i], means you are checking same element which you have stored now

```js
function small(array){
    var smallest = array[0];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[i];
            count = 0;
        }
        if(smallest===array[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
 console.log(small([5,6,2,2,2]));
```

Comment: @Kaps Thanks a lot! resetting it to 0 worked. What's the logic behind that? Because it was already set to 0

Comment: @grasshopper  whenever you will get new smallest, then reset is required. Why its 0 not 1. because you have condition later which is checking with smallest === arr[i], means you are checking same element which you have stored now

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie dry run it with reset 1 you will get to know why 0 not 1.

Comment: @Kaps I know. didn't notice there was no `else if` there (which should be). Already deleted comment.

Answer (score 2):

you can use two loops here and first get the smallest number and then count the number of times it occurs. Time complexity will still be O(n).

```js
function small(array){
    var smallest = array[0];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(array[i] < smallest) {
           smallest = array[i];
       }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       if(smallest===array[i]) {
           count++;
       }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log( small([5,6,2,2,2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time the loop runs, `smallest` is the first item in the array, as that's how you declare it

```
var smallest = array[0];
```

So on the first iteration, `smallest` is already `5`, and so is `array[i]`, as it's currently also `array[0]`, that's where the loop starts, so they are the same, meaning your condition is true on the first iteration, and the count increases.

You're really going about this the wrong way.
The easiest would be to use `Math.min` to find the smallest number in the array, and then just filter the array based on that, and see how many indices are left

```js
function small(arr) {
    let min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    return arr.filter(val => val === min).length;
}

console.log(small([5, 6, 2, 2, 2]));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this recalculate the minimum of all integers for each item in the array? (as opposed to storing the minimum first)

Comment: No it wouldn't, but I can make absolutely sure that isn't an issue by using the third argument for `Array.filter`

Comment: What I mean is, the filter callback is executed for each item in the original array. Inside that callback you are calling a function (Math.min). How does each invocation of the filter  callback not invoke Math.min,which in turn would recalculate the minimum (albeit always the same result) for the entire array? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - that's correct, it would indeed call `Math.min` several times, not that it matters much for this example, but I moved it out of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `count` to 0 if you replace `smallest`

```
function small(array){
    var smallest = array[0];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[i];
            count = 0;
        }
        if(smallest===array[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
small([5,6,2,2,2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set smallest to

```
array[0]
```

and if statement says

```
smallest = array[i]
```

it is always true.
You need to set smallest = 0 or smallest = 1.